# Loading CSV column in pandas with ints and blanks

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV with a column that contains blanks and an int (0).

When loading the csv via

```
pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), dtype={'VA (B-C) Rec':str}
```

The warning that the column *VA (B-C) Rec* still as mixed types. Not sure what to do b/c it takes 20m to load this CSV.

Comment: pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), dtype=object)?

Comment: @Wen still takes a while. Still running after 3m

Comment: How about change after read ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: df=pd.read_csv(StringIO(data)), then change the certain column type to object

Comment: the reading as a DF takes 20m though. I was hoping I could speed it up with these additional parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because the data was in a string format but, the encoding wasn't specified. Once `data.encoding = 'utf-8'` was set, reading took less than ten seconds.